# ng repeat not displaying content

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I got a basic problem, though I don't figure out, why it's not working:

```
<article id="desktop">
    <h3>Content: </h3>
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="x in storage">
            name: {{x.name}}
        </li>
    </ul>
</article>
```

And my angular:

```
$scope.storage = [];    
...

$scope.showDesktop = function(){        
$http.get("/getDesktop").then(function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
        $scope.storage.push({
            name: response.data[i]
        });
    }
    console.log($scope.storage);
    return;
});        
}
```

There must be an syntax error but I can't figure out where it is.
I alredy looked in the documentation and copied the ng-repeat syntax, but it still doesn't work.

Console.log shows just the correct content.

My Spring controller looks like:

```
    //Returns Desktop
@GetMapping("/getDesktop")
public ArrayList<String> getDesktop() throws Exception {
    ArrayList<String> itemNames = new ArrayList<>();

    if(kdxF.getLogged() && kdxF.getUser() != null) {
        itemNames = kdxF.showDesktop();
    }else {
        throw new Exception("Not logged in!");
    }   

    return itemNames;
}
```

Comment: Are you able to print {{$scope.storage}} anywhere in your html?

Comment: @L.Figueredo I wasn't no. But I solved my problem alsoready, was an error in the backend. =)
thanks, tho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to scope the variable in order to access it from the html

```
var storage = []; //It is a private declaration and html has no access to it
```

Convert it with `$scope.storage = [];` and the ng-repeat will have access to it then.

Also don't forget to change the variable in api too

```
$http.get("/getDesktop").then(function(response){
    for(var i = 0; i<response.data.length; i++){
        $scope.storage.push({
            name: response.data[i]
        });
    }
    console.log($scope.storage);
    return;
}, function (err){
    //log the error callback
    console.log(err);
});
```

**Edited:** One possible issue could be either due to ng-repeat tracking sequence. For that we use `ng-repeat="x in storage track by $index"`

Be insure that you are logging the error response in api calling.

Comment: I alredy tried that - but still doesn't display the content.

Comment: please see my edition, may be you have not updated the variable in the api calling

Comment: I did.. but still nothing.

Comment: could you use ng-repeat="x in storage track by $index"

Comment: Tried, but still nothing displayed.

Comment: Is the html lies in the ng-controller tag?